# JavaScript Object Inheritance with IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, iife

I won't lie I'm awesome with JavaScript nor that I understood the IIFE concept in its totality, but since I read [jQuery Best Practices](http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices) and then first met the concept plus some researching made later, I came up to this:

```
( function( MyObject, window, document, $, undefined ) {

    var privateVariable = {};

    MyObject.publicVariable;

    function privateMethod() {}

    myObject.publicMethod() {}

}( window.MyObject = window.MyObject || {}, window, document, window.jQuery ) );
```

Although it works nicely as expected I recently felt the need of some form of abstraction so i could create a base class with shared properties and methods and child objects with their own logic.

That way I wouldn't need, let's say, repeat a *getter* common to all children in each individual object.

I've searched about this matter, of course, but I didn't find specific information on how to implement such feature with this concept.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a construction method:

```
( function( MyObject, window, document, $, baseClass) {

    // calling base class for common properties, methods
    baseClass && baseClass.call(MyObject);

    var privateVariable = {};

    MyObject.publicVariable;

    function privateMethod() {}

    myObject.publicMethod() {}

}( window.MyObject = window.MyObject || {}, window, document, window.jQuery, baseClass ) );
```

Comment: So, doing this, I would have the so called *getter* in parent and, just as example, the *setter* in children classes? Also, would I be able to access variables in parent context without making them public by preppending the Object name? With my knowledge of JavaScript, looks good to me, but is this a valid practice?

Comment: To me, there is no such best or valid practices, if it works for us then simply use it :). In the end, Javascript is not a OOP language, trying to code JS like coding C#, Java will end up losing the strength of the language.

Comment: The closest I've got working was this, but it looks like more of a pompous Dependency Injection rather than inheritance to me, afterall, since I'm injecting the here called Base Object I could use `Base.getFoo()` directly Instead of `Child.prototype.getFoo ()`

Comment: [Here's](http://output.jsbin.com/vufehiyadi) a different approach I've got that looks a bit more like inheritance but as far as I understood the IIFE concept injects itself and here I had to create a global variable otherwise I can't use `new`. Would be possible to merge both worlds?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing the IIFE is providing you is an enclosed scope. You do not need
multiple IIFEs, unless there is some reason you have not stated. So, first,
let's cover what the "best practices" link you read is really suggesting.

In the browser environment, all JavaScript is executed within a single scope.
Thus, the following two scripts will have the same scope despite being
different files:

**script_a.js**

```
var foo = 'bar'
console.log('foo = ', foo)
```

**script_b.js**

```
if (foo === 'bar') {
  console.log('foo is still bar')
}
```

But if we wrap each script in an IIFE, the scope changes and `script_b` will
no longer function:

**script_a.js**

```
(function ()  {
  var foo = 'bar'
  console.log('foo = ', foo)
}())
```

**script_b.js**

```
(function () {
  if (foo === 'bar') { // throws an error because `foo` is not defined
    console.log('foo is still bar')
  }
}())
```

Given the nature of web development, and jQuery with plugins, many scripts get
loaded and the global scope gets polluted. This can result in hard to identify
side effects. Therefore it is recommended that you contain your code within its
own scope. This is accomplished with the IIFE since functions have their own
local scope and the function is invoked on load.

Based on your [example](http://jsbin.com/vufehiyadi/1/edit?html,js,output), it looks like you merely want composable
objects so that you can keep them separated in individual files during
development. This is a clear usage of the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html):

**script_c.js**

```
var MY_NAMESPACE = (function () {
  var privateFoo = 'foo'

  return {
    getFoo: function getFoo () {
      return privateFoo
    }
  }
}())
```

**script_d.js**

```
(function (NAMESPACE) {
  var privateBar = 'bar'

  NAMESPACE.getBar = function getBar () { return privateBar }
}(MY_NAMESPACE))
```

**script_e.js**

```
console.log(MY_NAMESPACE.getFoo()) // 'foo'
console.log(MY_NAMESPACE.getBar()) // 'bar'
```

Notice that `MY_NAMESPACE` is a global variable. This is where you have to
be unique, as it is susceptible to being overwritten by some later loaded
script that could overwrite your global variable.

I haven't used it, but there is a library called [stampit](https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit) that
expands upon this pattern and makes it simple to use.

With all of that said, you can then extend your `MY_NAMESPACE` object into
a new object:

**script_f.js**

```
var CHILD_NAMESPACE = Object.create(MY_NAMESPACE)

CHILD_NAMESPACE.fooOrBar = (function (NS) {
  var counter = 0
  return function () {
    var answer = (counter % 2 === 0) ? NS.getFoo() : NS.getBar()
    counter += 1
    return answer
  }
}(CHILD_NAMESPACE))
```

Of course, all of the above scripts could be contained within a single overall
IFFE to completely contain your code within its own scope.